# MBed TLS Tutorial Secure Connection Refernce

Tags: tls1.2, mbedtls

Referring to the example as in https://mbed-tls.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kb/how-to/mbedtls-tutorial/ (secure connection) does the secret key exchange takes place in-between server and client.

Is there any flowchart / diagram that states what happens during the server client connection - how the keys are exchanged and what types of certs are exchanged, I mean like .pem, X.509 etc?

Can we take this way that be it any type of certificate the code implementation is the same for all TLS communication?